# Angular unrelated components communication

Tags: angular

I have a component A which displays a list of items
If i click on any item i am redirected to component B which displays some details about that item

My problem is the following: let's say i am on the detail page of an item, if someone deletes the item from the component A, all actions inside component B should fail.

What i am trying to do, if an action inside component B fails, redirect to component A, and trigger a function, probably ngOnInit, to get the list of available items.

This could be easily fixable with a simple window.reload, but i want to find a better solution.

Any suggestions on doing it without creating a shared service?

Comment: I believe that  this.router.navigate(['pathToComponentA']); which should be called on particular action fail is enough. If componentA has fetching call in ngOnInit, you will achieve it.

Comment: @MarcinMilewicz , i already tried it and it doesnt work